# Can I define the polynomial ring A[x] with an isomorphism f: A ---> A[x]?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I'm sorry if this isn't an appropriate question for MO. I've been reading here for a while, but I still haven't got a good grasp of what's a *good* question.
Given a field A and the polynomial ring A[x], we order the elements of A in any sequence and we define the isomorphism $f\colon A\to A[x]$ such that every element a<sub>n</sub>$\mapsto$a<sub>n</sub> x<sup>n</sup>, a<sub>n</sub> $\in$ A, x<sup>n</sup> $\in$ A[x].

Can this be considered an alternate definition for A[x], is it just wrong, or is it the same as the canonical one?

Andy

Comment: Whatever that is, it's not an isomorphism.  

Comment: If A is a field, then A and A[x] are never isomorphic (since the former one is a field and the latter one isn't). The closest thing you might be searching for is the universal property of the polynomial ring http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Universal_property_of_the_polynomial_ring. It doesn't rely on enumeration and basically says "R[x] is the simplest ring that adjoints to R some element x without any special properties"

Comment: For most rings, $A$ and $A[x]$ are not isomorphic. I'd be surprised if you can find any ring with that property which is not something extremely huge (like compact operators on some infinite dimensional Hilbert space).
For instance, if $A$ is an algebra over a field with nice finiteness properties, the polynomial $A[x]$ will have bigger dimension.

Comment: Right, what I really meant was A is a domain, but still, I guess that does not change things. Thanks for the reference

Comment:  I hope this doesn't come off too harshly: I don't understand this question. You say you will define a map from A to A[x]. The proposed map is supposed to be described by the formula a_n \to a_n x^n. This formula doesn't make sense, because I don't know what n is. For example, if R is the real numbers, where do I send 17? Does it go to 17, to 17 x, to 17 x^{17}, or to someplace completely different? Where does \pi go? I don't know whether the question you are thinking of is a good question, but the question you have written is not, because is not clear what you are thinking of.

Comment: The question says: "we order the elements of A in any sequence", so my understanding is that we arbitrarily order A as a_1, a_2, .... Of course, given that we want the indices to be natural numbers, we can't do this for any uncountable field (or ring, for that matter).

Comment: Well, we DO have a trivial example if we consider nonunital rings: we can say that the 0 ring is isomorphic to its ring of polynomials 0[x] (I just wanted to mention this little detail).

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are thinking, thanks to Gabe's comment. But f isn't much of a map. It is not a map of rings, as  f(a+b) is not f(a)+f(b), and f(ab) is not f(a)f(b). It is very far from covering A[x] - it doesn't hit any polynomial which has more than one term in it. So this is not an isomorphism; it has basically none of the properties an isomorphism should have. I also don't know what you could have meant by "the usual isomorphism". A guideline to what makes a good question might be that you understand what all the words in it mean.

Comment: @Jose: This is a minor point, but the zero ring is unital.  It just happens to satisfy the equation 0=1.

Comment: @Dadvi: yes, n is a natural number, and I've never written about a "usual isomorphism", I asked if that could have been an alternate definition to the canonical definition of the polynomial ring over A, A[x]. Let us conisder S the ser of all the infinite sequences (a_0,a_1,...,a_n) of elements of A such that there exists an n_0 in N with the property that for all n > n_0, a_n = 0. S is a subset of A^N. The sum will be thus defined: (a_0,a_1,...a_n)+(b_0,...b_n)=(a_0+b_0,...,a_n+b_n) and the product as (a_0,...,a_n)(b_0,...,b_n)=(c_0,...,c_n), with c= Sum of (a_j *b_j) from j+k=i.

Comment: (c_0,...,c_n) is in S. Thus, S is a commutative unitary ring with unit 1_s=(1,0,0,0...). Moreover, all the elements (a,0,0,0...) in A are a subring A_1 of S isomorphic to A. We define x as (0,1,0,0...) and x^n as (0,0,0,0...,a,0,0,0...) with n zeroes before a. A polynomial will be an object of the form a_0+a_1 x+...+a_n_0 x^n_0.

I consider this to be the "canonical definition of A[x]". I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I surely will be next time.

Comment: @Scott: I was following the convention that 1 must satisfy 1<>0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question seems to involve a construction of a set-theoretic map, and the indexing (natural numbers?) suggests that A is assumed to have a countable underlying set.  That map doesn't even yield a surjection of sets.

I would like to reinterpret the question in the following way: How much structure do we need to forget in order for there to exist an isomorphism $A \to A[x]$?  YBL pointed out that there is never an A-algebra isomorphism (if A is nonzero) and that there can be a ring-theoretic isomorphism if A is big enough.  If A has an infinite underlying set, then there exist isomorphisms on the underlying sets.  It is potentially interesting to ask when we get isomorphisms on the underlying additive groups: it is sufficient for A to have a polynomial ring structure, but that is far from necessary: e.g., A could be any field of infinite dimension over its prime field.

Regarding your last question, you can define a polynomial ring using a sequence of embeddings $f_n: a \mapsto ax^n$ together with a specified multiplication law.  This is a special case of the monoid ring construction.  I'm not sure if this was the construction you initially had in mind, but it doesn't yield an isomorphism, since it isn't a single map.

Comment: The construction I had in mind was something like that, thanks. Still, I can't really remember why I wanted it to be an isomorphism. Thanks a lot for the answer 

Answer (score 12):

$A$ is never isomorphic to $A[x]$ as an $A$-algebra. Because, for any $A$-algebra $B$, the set of $A$-algebras homomorphisms

- $Hom_A(A,B)$ has only one element: the unit map $a\mapsto a\cdot 1$.
- $Hom_A(A[x],B)$ is canonically identified with the set $B$: $b$ corresponds to $\sum a_nx^n\mapsto \sum a_n b^n$.

But it is possible for $A$ and $A[x]$ to be isomorphic as rings. Take $A = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n,\ldots]$ a polynomial ring in a infinity of variables, then $A \to A[x_0]$ that sends $x_{i+1}$ to $x_i$ is an isomorphism of $k$-algebras (not of $A$-algebras).